# How can I store multiple dynamic products in stripe checkout webforms (ASP.NET C#) I tried a lot but static it's worked but dynamic not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

here is the code:-
static I used its worked fine.. how can I store product dynamically in using asp.net c#

```
 LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
  {     
   for (int i = 0; i < dtOrder.Rows.Count; i++){  
    new SessionLineItemOptions
    {
       Name=dtOrder.Rows[i]["ProductName"].toString(),
        Currency="cad",
      Amount =Convert.toInt64(dtOrder>Rows[i]["Price"])*100,
      Quantity = 1,
    },
   }
  },
```

Comment: Show us the dynamic code that didn't work.

Comment: please check this..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "statically" and "dynamically". Can you explain exactly what you mean by that? Perhaps by showing us both your static attempt and your dynamic attempt in the question, we'll get a better idea of what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Extending the snippet shown in the API reference [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=dotnet), we can replace `Price = 'price_123'` with `PriceData` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=dotnet#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data)) like so:

```
var options = new SessionCreateOptions
{
  SuccessUrl = "https://example.com/success",
  CancelUrl = "https://example.com/cancel",
  PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
  {
    "card",
  },
  LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
  {
    new SessionLineItemOptions
    {
      PriceData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataOptions
      {
        Currency = "usd",
        UnitAmount = 50000,
        ProductData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataOptions
        {
          Name = "some product name",
        }
      },
      Quantity = 2,
    },
  },
  Mode = "payment",
};
var service = new SessionService();
service.Create(options);
```

You can find all the type definitions in [the source code](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/tree/master/src/Stripe.net/Services/Checkout/Sessions).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but my problem is how can I store products dynamically. statically I understand.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic, then? The answer here is defining products & prices during the session create request by using `price_data` and `product_data`. Can you explain what you need that this does not provide?

Comment: I get data from the database and I want to store data using for loop in the new SessionLineItemOptions when I am using for loop in between LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions> then it provides me a syntax error.

Comment: Well sure, just separate that out into a step before the request. `List<SessionLineItemOptions> sessionItems = ... ;  SessionCreateOptions { LineItems = sessionItems, ...}`

Answer (score 0):

I integrated Mulitple Account Payment of stripe and fixed the issue like this
and its working for me now , you can also use simple checkout method like this  fetching dynamically product from db

List lineItemsOptions = new List();
string cmdText = "select * from tableorder where sessionid='"+ sessionid + "'";
DataSet ds = dbm.getDs(cmdText);

```
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {

            var currentLineItem = new SessionLineItemOptions
            {
                Name = row["ProductName"].ToString(),
                Amount = 100,//Convert.ToInt32( row["variationPrice"].ToString()),
                Currency = "usd",
                Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row["Quantity"].ToString()),
               
            };
            lineItemsOptions.Add(currentLineItem);

         

        }
```

StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = ".......................................";
var options = new SessionCreateOptions();

```
           options = new SessionCreateOptions
            {
                PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
              {
                "card",
              },

                LineItems = lineItemsOptions,
                PaymentIntentData = new SessionPaymentIntentDataOptions
                {
                    ApplicationFeeAmount = 1,
                },
                Mode = "payment",
                SuccessUrl = "https://www.......com/success.aspx",
                CancelUrl = "https://example.com/cancel",
            };
       

        var requestOptions = new RequestOptions
        {
            StripeAccount = ".............",
        };
        var service = new SessionService();
        Session session = service.Create(options, requestOptions);
```